# Confused about coroutines scope constructor syntax

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand the syntax for coroutines constructor.

```
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
```

I know the parameter need Coroutine Context class. 
What I don't understand is how can we add 2 different object?
Dispatchers.Main class is MainCoroutineDispatcher
and viewModelJob class is Job.
Is there any explanation about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoroutineScope` is not a constructor but a function, defined as:

```
public fun CoroutineScope(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineScope = ...
```

The parameter is the interface `CoroutineContext` which itself defines a plus operator:

```
public operator fun plus(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineContext = ...
```

The `plus` operator returns another `CoroutineContext`. `Dispatchers.Main` and `Job` implement the interface `CoroutineContext`.

That said,  `Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob` is the invocation of `plus` that constructs another `CoroutineContext`. Internal this results in a collection of the both instances.